# Marionette collection view does not update when model added

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I am new to Marionette. So may be its pretty basic.

I have a collection initialized globally and is empty during creation.

```
App.Colors= Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : App.Color,
    comparator : "price"    
});


var appColors = new App.Colors();
```

If I create a Marionette collection view with this empty collection.

```
var colorview= new App.ColorView({collection:appColors});
```

and later on add to the collection appColors.

```
appColors.add({code:'red'})
```

Shouldn't the view be updated automatically since it listens to collection.add. I know it will work fine if I type:

```
colorview.collection.add({code:'red'})
```

Comment: What does your CollectionView look like? If you pass it a non-empty collection do those models get rendered as expected?

Comment: yes, they do get rendered.

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to work, you must bind the view rendering to the collection add event, so basicly in your view declaration you must have something like this :

```
App.ColorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
        ...
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: The collectionView in Marionette already adds this for you. Anyways, this was one of the first things I tried. Doesnt work :(

Comment: Have you tested `colorview.collection.add({code:'red'})` ? `I know it will work fine` is not an assertion that a computer scientist count on :)

Comment: Yes, ofcourse I have tried this. I knew I would get suggestions to try this so wanted to state what is obvious. :) But this is not how I want to update the view. The module is pretty complex, I have stated the issue in simple code. The data gets updated in a different module, but view is rendered separately based on a lot of calculations.

Comment: Are you sure that when you call `appColors.add({code:'red'})` the `appColors` and `colorview.collection` are pointing to the same object ?